# AssertionError: expected null to deeply equal XXX

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, vitest

I use vitest to test my components and hooks.

I have a `useLocalTime` hook that I want to test, but the `renderHook` function from `@testing-library/react` always returns null.

Any idea why ?

Here is the hook :

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {Dayjs} from "dayjs";

interface Props {
    dayJsObject: Dayjs;
    format?: string;
}

const capitalizeFirstLetters = (text: string) => {
    return text
        .toLowerCase()
        .split(" ")
        .map((word) => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))
        .join(" ");
};

export const useLocalTime = ({dayJsObject, format}: Props) => {
    const [formattedTime, setFormattedTime] = useState<string | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const updateTime = () => {
            const currentTime = dayJsObject.format(format ?? "D MMMM YYYY LTS");

            setFormattedTime(capitalizeFirstLetters(currentTime));
        };

        const interval = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);

        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [dayJsObject, format]);

    return formattedTime;
};
```

Here is the test :

```
import {renderHook} from "@testing-library/react";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import {useLocalTime} from "ui/hooks/useLocalTime";

describe("useLocalTime", () => {
    it("should return the formatted time", () => {
        const dayJsObject = dayjs("2022-06-16T14:49:35.718Z");
        const {result} = renderHook(() => useLocalTime({dayJsObject}));

        expect(result.current).toEqual("16 June 2022 14:49:35");
    });
});
```

Here is the error :

```
AssertionError: expected null to deeply equal '16 June 2022 14:49:35'

- Expected: 
"16 June 2022 14:49:35"

+ Received: 
null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `updateTime` in your `useLocalTime` hook isn't firing due to it being in an 1000ms interval. It's returning the default state (`null`) provided in the hook.

1. You need to use [fake timers](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks) simulate the interval and have your test as such

```js
describe("useLocalTime", () => {
    it("should return the formatted time", () => {
        jest.useFakeTimers();
        const dayJsObject = dayjs("2022-06-16T14:49:35.718Z");
        const {result} = renderHook(() => useLocalTime({dayJsObject}));
        act(() => {
         jest.advanceTimersByTime(1100);
        });
        expect(result.current).toEqual("16 June 2022 14:49:35");
    });
});
```

2. Or instead you can update the hook to call `updateTime` on initial load.

Comment: Very clear. Thank you very much